# removing spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string and managing the carriage return function iby javascript function

Tags: javascript, string, forms, textarea

I have a textare in a form. When I click on it I want the carriage to return at the very beginning. I have this function included in the JavaScript, but it only works when I click in the first row. So I need to fix that function.

The second thing is that when I start to type in that area and I keep on writing spaces at the beginning, it will keep on removing them. I have this function, but it doesn't work. So if it's possible to fix that?

I also have the function for removing the spaces at the end when clickcing of control button, but it doesn't work either. I am controlling the length of the string which is in the textarea by the check button. Every time I add space at the beginning or at the end the space is not removed. I would appreaciate any opinion or help.

```js
function Start(){
  document.getElementById("TA2").innerHTML = "\r";
}                

function RemoveFirst(word){    
  if(word.charAt(0) == ' ' || word.charAt(0) == '\n'){
    word.slice(1);
  }

  return word;
}

function RemoveLast(word){
  while(word.charAt(length-1) == ' '){
    word.slice(length-1);
  }
  return word;
}            

function TellMe(check){
  document.getElementById("finaltext").innerHTML = check + "The word has: " + check.length + " letters";
}
```

```css
form, input, textarea {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form name="form2">
  <textarea onmousedown="Start()" onekeypress="TA2.value = RemoveFirst(TA2.value)" id="TA2" name="TA2" cols="20" rows="5">
  </textarea><br />
  <input onclick="TA2.value = RemoveLast(TA2.value)" type="button" name="but1" value="control" /><br />
  <input onclick="TellMe(TA2.value)" type="button" name="butt2" value="check" /><br />
  <div>
    <p id="finaltext"></p><br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your problem is that `word.slice(1);` doesn't change `word` - it returns a new string

Comment: ok yeah thanks I just solved the problem by using trim() function instead

Comment: interesting, since `trim` doesn't change the variable either, it returns a new string too - so you must've made more changes than that :p

Comment: well yeah you're right :D I did this: `code function TellMe(check){ document.getElementById("finaltext").innerHTML = "&quot" + check.trim() + "&quot" + " string has " + check.trim().length + " letters"; }  ` and I passed the value of textarea into the atribute of function